# How does a telegram bot work in Linux?

Tags: linux, root, tcp, socket, port

I wrote a simple telegram bot and it works great without conflicting with my firewall. But my question is this, in the firewall I have ports 80 and 443 allowed for my site, but when I write a TCP socket in Python that should work through port 443 or port 80, the OS tells me that I need to run `the program from the user's root`, but if I start the bot, then the OS does not swear at all about the rights and the bot works quietly. If I still decide to run a socket on port 443 or 80, then the OS replies `that these ports are busy`.

So, please explain to me why the telegram bot does not conflict with processes and ports?

My server is Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What does "start the bot" entail, exactly?

Comment: On most systems, only `root` is allowed to open ports < 1024.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux) question with a huge list of answers

Comment: By launch I mean: python3 bot.py

Comment: Bot works not through webhook, but through executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

Comment: Are you running a web server? If you did, the bot (running as root) would likely not be able to bind to those ports.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the [Telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) works through the bot making *outgoing* HTTPS requests (to the remote port 443), the same as your web browser. There are usually no restrictions for doing that.

On the other hand, accepting *incoming* HTTP/HTTPS requests would require binding to local ports 80 and 443, and binding to ports below 1024 is restricted to root in many Unix-likes.

If you get an "Address already in use" error (or similar) when binding to a local port, then you probably already have another program using the port, likely a web server in the case of 80 and 443.

(I'm not exactly sure about the details on what you're doing, as there's no code shown in the question, and I suspect the error messages are also not accurate.)